# Mass updating/install on Windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

I currently use LogMeIn to remotely manage a bunch of computers around the country. However, I am curious as if there is a way to make updating on them automatic and install and make system changes on ALL the machines remotely.

**This is not a question about LogMeIn. This is a more general based question.**

I also should mention, I would like to also expand this to Adobe, Java, and other related services. Is there a way to push CLI to the targeted machines? These machines are also not all in a corporate network. They consist of many networks for many businesses and home users.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run WSUS directly over the net using HTTPS and (I believe) client side certificates. Put together this provides a ready way to manage your updates remotely.

We use Solar Wind's Patch manager for pushing additional products and updates via the standard WSUS agent. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

For updating apps such as Adobe Reader, Java, Flash, etc, take a look at Ninite (and Ninite Pro). It's a fire-and-forget way of updating a lot of commonly-used tools. Ninite Pro is a bit more versitile than standard Ninite and can download apps to a local store rather than having to download them over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

There are several non-MS solutions that can help you. Some require a remote service, others can be done with cli or psexec (winexe if you are in linux) or even puppet and similar. While a AD might help in some configs, it's not required... but for remote users, a vpn might be recommended to avoid publishing a PC on to the internet. Check [openvpn](http://openvpn.net)* for a easy, but secure vpn. (don't even try the windows vpn, all pptp vpn are very weak).

- [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/)
- [npackd](http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/)
- [wpkg](http://windowspackager.org/)
- [Ninite](http://ninite.com)
- [PDQ-Deploy](http://www.adminarsenal.com/pdq-deploy/main/)

The first 3 are free, the other 2 have both a free and paid version, with different features.

There are others that work only locally , with more or less features, but might also be useful, specially for free software, open source, freeware,  etc:

- [FreeApps](http://www.freenew.net/windows.htm)
- [TGUP](http://tgup.net)
- [soft2base](http://www.soft2base.com/)
- [allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com)

* For setting up a openvpn, check this [easy manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide), in a few minutes you can interconnect all your machines just like a big local network.

Comment: Very useful list of alternatives

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Npackd](http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/) to manage the software on the computers. There is also a command line based client. You could also use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553) to remotely execute it if you do not wish to open an RDP connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can run WSUS with machines that aren't in a domain.  There's a set of registry keys that'll let you do this.  They're here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

As for Adobe, Java, etc., you could use psexec (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to script an update kick-off, but you'll need to run that as an account with credentials for the local machines (which it sounds like you have).